# Dynamic created iFrame with 0 width 0 height

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a dynamically created iFrame, which automatically loads its HTML through the following way:

```
        var newFrame = document.createElement('frame');
        newFrame.id = theId;
        newFrame.width = "200";
        newFrame.height = "200";
        newFrame.style.width = "200px";
        newFrame.style.height = "200px";
        newFrame.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI('<script type="text/javascript>var $ = parent.$;</script>' + data);
        $('#menuContent').append(newFrame);
```

But, on the page, the iFrame's `width` and `height` are both rendered as 0.
The content inside the iFrame is loaded properly (As seen through the dev tools). Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Here is an image of the loaded iFrame:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `frame` element, which is meant for use inside a `frameset` element and lacks `width` and `heigh` properties. Use an `iframe` element instead, i.e. change the first statement to

```
var newFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
```

Comment: Why didn't I see that??